# Can we transfer data through USB Host API to PC via USB cable?

Tags: android, usb

Please help me on this,

In my project I need to transfer data from android device(3.0 and above) to PC via USB cable
without depending on USB debugging mode option(USB debugging option should not be selected).

So is this possible to transfer data to PC with USB host API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can, just the way the cardock works.
The only difference the USB host function is that when android is in host mode it supplies the power.
This is device dependent and not API lvl dependent.
But you don't want the host function, as the pc is the host.
You want to be in accessory mode.
For more info, check: [Accessory mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an USB data transfer cable (also called USB data link cable) which

support API or SDK, then use the following code:

```
void CU2uDlg::OnOK() 
{
BYTE        buf[65530];
LPU2URET    pU2uRet;
BOOL        bRet;
int         ret;
CString     msgstr;

ret = u2u_open();
if (ret == -1){
    AfxMessageBox("Open U2U device Success.");
}else{
    msgstr.Format("Open U2U device fail，return：%d", ret);
    AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
    return;
}

//send data
bRet = u2u_SendData(buf, 65530, ret);
if(!bRet)
{
    msgstr.Format("Send data error，return：%d", ret);
    AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
    return;
}

//receive data
while (1){
    bRet = u2u_RecvData(recvData, dataLen, ret);
    if( !bRet )
    {
        msgstr.Format("Receive data error，return：%d", ret);
        AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
        u2u_close();
        return;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
u2u_close();


}
```

See:

[Reference1](http://www.cnblogs.com/LiuKaiFa/p/USB_data_link_cable_API.html), [Reference2](http://blog.csdn.net/zzkjliu/article/details/12838383)